# Vector of class objects

Tags: c++, class, stl, destructor, stdvector

I have created a vector of class objects. The following program crashes with

```
 "Pointer being freed was not allocated".
```

I have deep copied as well. I don't see where the double delete is happening. What am I missing ?.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;

    enum MessageType { HEADER, DATA, CLOSE};

    typedef class bufferElement{

    public:
        char *buffer ; //The actual data
        int64_t length; //length of the data
        MessageType messagetype;    

        /**
         * Copy constructor for the structure
         */
        bufferElement(const struct bufferElement &toCopy)
        {
            std::cout << "Copying the buffer vector - Copy Constructor for buffer" << std::endl;
            buffer = new char[toCopy.length];
            memcpy(buffer,toCopy.buffer,toCopy.length);
            length = toCopy.length;
            messagetype = toCopy.messagetype;
        }


        bufferElement()
        {
            buffer = NULL;
            length =0;
            messagetype = HEADER;
        }

        /**
         *  Initialises the vector element
         *  @param messagetype
         *  what type of message is the particular element.
         *  @param element
         *  The buffer element
         *  @param length_t
         *  The length/size of the buffer element
         */
        bufferElement(char *element, int64_t length_t, MessageType messagetype_t)   //constructor
        {
            std::cout << "The buffer element is Initialized" << std::endl;
            buffer = new char[length_t];
            messagetype = messagetype_t;
            length = length_t;
            memcpy(buffer, element, length_t);
        }

        ~bufferElement()
        {
            std::cout << "Freeing the buffer in the vector - Destructor" << std::endl;
            delete buffer;
            buffer = NULL;
        }


    } messageHolder;

    int main()
    {
        vector<messageHolder> v;
        for(int64_t i=0; i< 1000000000000000000; i++)
        {
            int size = rand()%10000+5;
            char *test = new char[size];
            messageHolder m(test, size, HEADER );
            v.push_back(m);

            if(rand()%3)
            {
                v.erase(v.begin());
            }

        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't looked at your code in detail, but if you think you need a copy constructor, you also need an assignment operator. And, why, why, why write this stuff anyway? Why not use std::string? Do you feel the need to write your own floating point types? No, I didn't think so.

Comment: We all had this "reinvent the wheel" phase. I think. Atleast i did too.

Comment: Well this is a stripped down version of a larger code I am working on.  I just wanted to reproduce the error with fewer lines. For the original, just string doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Naveen - But you did use std::vector to store your objects at one level. Why not at the next level?!

Comment: I never intended to say, "I don't want to use string or STL containers." It just doesn't work for my use case. In any case, I am just curious why this won't work, so any help on that would be great.

Comment: Overloading the assignment operator got it working. Thanks Neil.

Comment: "Do you feel the need to write your own floating point types?" - and even if you do, do you rewrite an incomplete and hence buggy portion of that implementation into multiple classes just so that your floating point value can have an associated `MessageType` in this class, and perhaps some other associated data in another? Or do you, like, reuse code? :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use `delete[]` instead of `delete`, since you are freeing an array.

By the way, in `main()`, you should also invoke `delete[] test;`, otherwise, you'll get a memory leak.

Comment: Yea, got that fixed. But nevertheless, it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

In general I would avoid using objects with pointers as members (like buffer in your bufferElement) as types in vector (or any other stl container for that matter) without a copy constructor AND an assignment operator. If the destructor frees that pointer it's a recipe for destruction. You should eighter 
a) provide both the copy ctr and the assignment op 
OR 
b) don't use pointers (use smart pointers like boost::scoped_ptr or boost:shared_ptr or even in your case auto_ptr) which I favor more